# how can I detect the completion of an animation triggered by CATransaction

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, catransaction

I have a CALayer which I merely create and add to a subview of my view controller's main view in the controller's initWithNibName:
And then, I perform the following animation:

```
  [CATransaction begin];
  [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2];
  [logoLayer setOpacity:0];
  [CATransaction commit];
```

How can I tell when this animation is done? the performSelector: delayed by 2 secs. approach doesn't seem "the right way" to go about it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), `[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:]` could be used for what you want.

It says

> The completion block object is guaranteed to be called (on the main thread) as soon as all animations subsequently added by this transaction group have completed (or have been removed.) If no animations are added before the current transaction group is committed (or the completion block is set to a different value,) the block will be invoked immediately.

Try adding something like this before you `begin` the animation transaction.

```
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Action after the animation completion
}];
```

Comment: Operative word in that doc is “subsequently.” Don’t think (as I first did) that the completion block applies to the entire transaction. It just applies to animations added to the transaction after it’s set.